# Which Ubuntu will work?

Tags: installation

I've just built a new computer using an AMD A6-3650 APU with AMD Radeon 6530 HD Graphics 2.6GHz Socket FM1 100W Quad-Core Processor and a GIGABYTE GA-A75M-D2H FM1 AMD A75 (Hudson D3) HDMI SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.0 Micro ATX AMD Motherboard with G.SKILL Ripjaws Series 8GB (2 x 4GB) 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 1600 (PC3 12800) Desktop Memory Model F3-12800CL9D-8GBRL.

12.04 wouldn't install, and 10.04 hangs up after I select English as my language, whereupon a second language selection screen appears and freezes. Then I can't shut down except by turning off the power supply. Memory check passes (although then goes into endless loop).

I'm not comfortable fiddling around with a lot of code, just want a version that will run.

Thanks
John

Comment: Hardware support usually *improves* from version to version, so your chances with the latest version are better than with an older one, especially with new shiny hardware. I would start by investigating the "wouldn't install" issue with 12.04. Or maybe trying the current snapshot of 12.10 just to see if the problem has been fixed there.

Answer (score 1):

As best I can figure out, no version of Ubuntu will work with the AMD A4-3400. However, Fedora 17 ode works very well. Wish Ubuntu could address issues. Best to all, J